Problems with Apple-supplied code for font activation
I'm working through an Apple WWDC 2019 video about fonts, which includes this sample code for registering (enabling) fonts with the OS :
static func registerFamilies(_ names: [FontFamily], _ registrationHandler: 
    (([Error], Bool) -> Bool)?) {
    let fontURLs = names.flatMap({ $0.urls })
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs(fontURLs as CFArray, .persistent, true) {
        (errors: CFArray, done: Bool) -> Bool in
        return processHandler(errors: errors, done: done, registrationHandler) 
    }
}

However, this flags several errors:

Cannot find type "FontFamily" in scope;
Static methods must only be declared on a type
Cannot find processHandler in scope.

A static function affects all instances of a class, so presumably the absence of a defined class "FontFamily" is causing two errors. But it's unclear to me what that type should be.
Presumably I have to create my own processHandler function that does... something.
I've imported CoreText and Foundation. What am I missing?
I have found a simpler version of the function here:
iOS 13 Custom Fonts download and installation
Zago's answer, which they created from the same WWDC presentation, gives:
let fontUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "ttf")

CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs([fontUrl] as CFArray, .persistent, true) { (errors, done) -> Bool in
        if(done) {
            print("Done")
        }
        print(errors as Array)
        return true
    }

I guess my question is: what benefit to the developer is there in Apple's more complex and partial/incomplete example?

I don’t think the second error is connected to the others or fond handling in any way. Are you working in a playground? Other than that this question is most likely of interest

@JoakimDanielson Thanks. Yes, I found that answer with the simpler version of the function, but it causes an uncaught exception for me.

What is the exception?

@Willeke I've put in the first line. Do you want the whole trace?

The code from the WWDC talk does not compile on its own, there is no FontFamily type in Swift or in the Apple libraries. The second code should work as far as I can tell. Did you verify that fontUrl is not nil?

@MartinR Ah: it wasn't nil, but it wasn't a URL type. That's fixed the code, but it would be nice to know why Apple presents an incomplete and complex version, in an explanation of their new API.

My guess is that they had a sample program which uses a custom FontFamily type to hold the to-be-registered fonts. But if that program is not published then we can only speculate. – What is important is that there is a CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs function which takes an array of URLs (as CFArray). Everything else is application specific.

@MartinR I know that's the API. But (without Zago's answer) I would still be none the wiser of how to use it, either from the presentation, or the documentation!
